# CakePHP 3 Rest API

Tags: mysql, rest, api, cakephp, basic-authentication

I'm implementing an API using CakePHP3 with a MySQL database.

Everything works fine. The endpoints are a secured with a Basic Authentication.

Now I have noticed that the performance is dreadful. I started some speed tests with loader.io and noticed that the response times are around 400ms.

I don't know why, but at one point i deactivated the AuthComponent of CakePHP and suddenly I only had a response time of 120ms.

So I started digging around. I then implemented my own BasicAuthentication by just reading the header and comparing the user & password with my users table in the database. I still have ~120ms response time. Is the CakePHP3 AuthComponent just bloated up? I also noticed while having the AuthComponent activated that my php-fpm uses a large amount of CPU. Without The AuthComponent it's practicly nothing.

I implemented the BasicAuth exactly as described in the CakePHP Documentation. I just don't know what is going on. I would prefer to use the actual CakePHP methods than implementing my own check. Has anybody else ever had this issue? I just don't understand what is going on.

Comment: This is interesting to me. We're building an API using Basic Auth and the AuthComponent as well. I haven't started optimizing/benchmarking it yet as it's in the preliminary stage. I'm going to start playing around with timing the AuthComponent to see if I can discover what's happening and will report back if I find anything. Improving it's performance would help regular applications as well.

Comment: I was mainly asking if somebody else has maybe experienced this kind of issue. 

I also wrote that I set up the Auth exactly like describe in the Documentation: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#using-basic-authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at last we found out what was causing the long response times. It wasn't the AuthComponent but more the DefaultPasswordHasher.

I wrote a new PasswordHasher (for testing purposes returning the password unhashed) and the speed went up by factor 3.

Answer (score 1):

In **config/app.php**

Set `'debug' = false;`